# Left align the toolbars by code

Tags: .net, winforms, toolbars

Is there a way to left align the toolbars (without leaving the "spaces") by code?
[image]

(say, when clicking to the button2)
[image]

PS
Also this situation

[image]
To "left align" means :
[image]

Comment: Left Align Toolbars means You need to change the postion of Menustrip something like that.?

Comment: I need that the toolbars from the first image be aligned like the toolbars in the second image.

Comment: Just so I can make sure I've understood the issue, is it that when you dock (DockStyle) you can't then apply a width? And as such, the width is much wider than you'd like.

Comment: @serhio Your question keeps changing! Is it possible the strips will overlap by "row". You've pictured it where everything lines up neatly on the X axis.

Comment: Dave, the question does not change. I need Align the toolbars to left, that means, as much to left possible, no "empty spaces" in a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Based upon your criteria changing quite dramatically, here is some code which will get you going. It is not perfect nor even close to being perfect!

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _otherStrips = new List<OtherStrips>();
    }

    private int _currentHeight = 0;
    private List<OtherStrips> _otherStrips;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var c in panel1.Controls)
        {
            if (c is ToolStrip)
            {
                ToolStrip ts = (ToolStrip)c;
                _otherStrips.Add(new OtherStrips() { Top = ts.Top, Width = ts.Width, Name = ts.Name });
                MoveToPosition(ts);
            }
        }
    }

    private void MoveToPosition(ToolStrip toolStrip)
    {
        bool isInline;
        toolStrip.Left = GetWidth(toolStrip, out isInline); 

        if (isInline)
            toolStrip.Top = GetTop(toolStrip);
    }

    private int GetWidth(ToolStrip ts, out bool isInline)
    {
        int result = 0;
        isInline = false;
        foreach (var item in _otherStrips)
        {
            if (item.Name == ts.Name)
                continue;

            if (item.Top == ts.Top)
            {
                isInline = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!isInline)
            return result;

        foreach (var item in _otherStrips)
        {
            if (item.Width == ts.Width)
                result += item.Width;
        }

        return result + 22;//hack since the width is out by about 22pixels. Not going to spend any time fixing this
    }

    private int GetTop(ToolStrip ts)
    {
        foreach (var item in _otherStrips)
        {
            if (item.Name == ts.Name)
                continue;

            if (item.Top == ts.Top)
                return item.Top;
        }

        _currentHeight += ts.Height;
        return _currentHeight;
    }
}

struct OtherStrips
{
    public int Top { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @serhio, I updated my answer. This is not perfect, but a good start

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to left align your ToolStrip

```
toolStrip1.Location = new Point(0, toolStrip1.Location.Y);
```

Comment: use the same code for toolStrip2 and toolStrip3 by just replacing the name.. i have tested, its working :)